# Docker compose isnt writing files or directories to host

Tags: docker, docker-compose, certbot

I am following the digital ocean tutorial to install wordpress via docker

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-wordpress-with-docker-compose

It says if the certbot is other than 0 I get the following error, there are no log files where I it says to look. Newish to docker thanks for helping all!

Edit: I’m noting none of the volumes that this docker-compose were created on the host

```
  Name                 Command               State           Ports       
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
certbot     certbot certonly --webroot ...   Exit 1                      
db          docker-entrypoint.sh --def ...   Up       3306/tcp, 33060/tcp
webserver   nginx -g daemon off;             Up       0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp 
wordpress   docker-entrypoint.sh php-fpm     Up       9000/tcp
```

Docker-compose.yml here

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:8.0
    container_name: db
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=wordpress
    volumes: 
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
    command: '--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password'
    networks:
      - app-network

  wordpress:
    depends_on: 
      - db
    image: wordpress:5.1.1-fpm-alpine
    container_name: wordpress
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      - WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=db:3306
      - WORDPRESS_DB_USER=$MYSQL_USER
      - WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=$MYSQL_PASSWORD
      - WORDPRESS_DB_NAME=wordpress
    volumes:
      - wordpress:/var/www/html
    networks:
      - app-network

  webserver:
    depends_on:
      - wordpress
    image: nginx:1.15.12-alpine
    container_name: webserver
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - wordpress:/var/www/html
      - ./nginx-conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - certbot-etc:/etc/letsencrypt
    networks:
      - app-network

  certbot:
    depends_on:
      - webserver
    image: certbot/certbot
    container_name: certbot
    volumes:
      - certbot-etc:/etc/letsencrypt
      - wordpress:/var/www/html
    command: certonly --webroot --webroot-path=/var/www/html --email sammy@example.com --agree-tos --no-eff-email --staging -d example.com -d www.example.com

volumes:
  certbot-etc:
  wordpress:
  dbdata:

networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: Can you update your question with docker logs output from your certbot died container?

Comment: There seems to be no logs or directory for the logs created when I run docker logs certbot

Comment: I’m also noting none of the volumes were created

Comment: Can you try to manually run the certbot container, using the same params to see the error? `docker run -v certbot-etc:/etc/letsencrypt....` . Of course, run it after the others have started

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The volumes being created here are named volumes.

To check named volumes run:
`docker-compose volume ls`

Also, per the comment above, you could check `certbot` logs with:
`docker-compose logs certbot`

The volumes and container logs won’t show up using docker unless you use the specific container and volume names which you can find with:
`docker-compose ls` and `docker-compose volume ls`

Or use the `docker-compose` variants above